# Passing div data from js to aspx.cs webmethod

Tags: asp.net, jquery

When I check a `checkbox` I want to send the data in div to `webmethod` which is written inside `Webservice` in aspx codebehind. my js is like this:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                if (editorContent != "") {
                    if (!($("#divCustomTemplateContent1:contains('<html>')"))) {
                        editorContent = "<html><head></head><body>" + editorContent + "</body></html>";
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "3.aspx/AddorRemoveViewInBrowser",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: "{'html':'" + encodeURIComponent(editorContent) + "',isAddorRemove:'add'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (returndata) {
                            alert(returndata.d);
                            $('#divCustomTemplateContent1').html(returndata.d);
                        }
                    });
                }
}
```

Here my problem is when data in div is like this

```
<table bgcolor="#8da2b2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" align="center">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="581">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" width="581">
                                <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 20px;" width="581">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#b73224" height="110">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 581px;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="581" height="110" align="left">
                                                                <img src="/App_Themes/Main/Images/Ec/TemplateImages/3s_header.jpg" border="0" alt="XYZ Company" width="581" height="110">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top" class="mainbar" width="550">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-family: Tahoma, Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; padding-top: 15px;" valign="top" align="left">
                                                                <h2 style="font-size: 18px; border-left: 10px solid #a02f27; padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0;
                                                                    padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 7px; margin: 0px;">
                                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ct etuer adipiscing elit</h2>
                                                                <p style="color: #333333; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;
                                                                    margin-right: 0;">
                                                                    Donec imperdiet, nibh sit amet pharetra placerat, tortor purus condimentum lectushttp://tinyurl.com/d5rel77,
                                                                    at dignissim nibh velit vitae sem. Nunc <a href="http://some-site.com/" style="color: #344692;">
                                                                        condimentum blandit</a> tortorphasellus facilisis neque vitae purus.</p>
                                                                <p style="color: #333333; margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-right: 0;">
                                                                    Aliquam facilisis nisl in nisi. Ut ultricies massa eget est. Donec eget orci eget
                                                                    urna aliquam egestas. Nulla vitae felis. <a href="http://some-site.com/" style="color: #344692;">
                                                                        Maecenas bibendum</a>, nunc eu aliquet ultricies, massa massa aliquet est, nec
                                                                    dignissim nisl ante eget lectus.</p>
                                                                <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 0; width: 100%;
                                                                    text-align: right; padding: 0;">
                                                                    <a href="#top" style="color: #344692; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 0; margin-left: 4px;
                                                                        margin-bottom: 0; margin-right: 0;">Back to top</a></p>
                                                                <img src="/App_Themes/Main/Images/Ec/TemplateImages/hr-big.gif" border="0" alt="hr" width="550" height="10" style="display: block;">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="551">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-family: Tahoma, Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; padding-top: 15px;" valign="top" align="left">
                                                                <h2 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 18px; border-left: 10px solid #a02f27;
                                                                    padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 7px; margin: 0px;">
                                                                    Fermentum quam donec imperde lorem ipsum dolar amet consect</h2>
                                                                <p style="color: #333333; margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;
                                                                    margin-right: 0;">
                                                                    <img src="/App_Themes/Main/Images/Ec/TemplateImages/main-content-inline-small.jpg" border="0" alt="Main Content Inline Small" hspace="10" width="147" height="147" align="left">Aliquam facilisis nisl in nisi. Ut ultricies massa eget est.
                                                                    Donec eget orci eget urna aliquam egestas. Nulla vitae felis. Maecenas bibendum,
                                                                    nunc eu aliquet ultricies, massa massa aliquet est, nec dignissim nisl ante eget
                                                                    lectus.Aliquam facilisis nisl in nisi. Ut ultricies massa eget est. Donec eget orci
                                                                    eget urna aliquam egestas. Nulla vitae felis. Maecenas bibendum, nunc eu aliquet
                                                                    ultricies, massa massa aliquet est, nec dignissim nisl ante eget lectus.%%%%last_name%%%%</p>
                                                                <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 0; width: 100%;
                                                                    text-align: right; padding: 0;">
                                                                    <a href="#top" style="color: #344692; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 0; margin-left: 4px;
                                                                        margin-bottom: 0; margin-right: 0;">Back to top</a></p>
                                                                <img src="/App_Themes/Main/Images/Ec/TemplateImages/hr-big.gif" border="0" alt="hr" width="550" height="10" style="display: block;">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table bgcolor="#8da2b2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="581">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; color: #333333;" align="center" valign="bottom" height="100">
                                                <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-right: 0; text-align: center;">
                                                    XYZ Company and the XYZ Company Logo are registered trademarks of <span>XYZ Company
                                                        Corp</span>.<br>
                                                    XYZ Company Corp - 123 Some Street, City, ST 99999. ph +1 4 1477 89 745</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the webmethod is not getting called at all. When i give simple data in for div then ther will be no errors.

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string AddorRemoveViewInBrowser(string html, string isAddorRemove)
        {
            string returnHtml = string.Empty;
            if (isAddorRemove == "add")
            {
                CampaignManager ocampaignmanger = new CampaignManager();
                returnHtml = ocampaignmanger.AddViewInbrowser(html);
            }
            else
            {
                CampaignManager ocampaignmanger = new CampaignManager();
                returnHtml = ocampaignmanger.RemoveViewInbrowser(html);
            }
            return returnHtml;
        }
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that is not called ? did you debug it and see that is not hit the `AddorRemoveViewInBrowser` ?

Comment: yes i have seen with debugging. I think i need to encode or json the data of div... but i dont know sytax

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to know that you have specified `contentType` and `dataType` to `json`. So in your case, data that is being sent to server and that's being sent back from the server has to be json data only.

do change like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    ....
    data: {'html':encodeURIComponent(editorContent),'isAddorRemove':'add'},
    ....
});
```

Secondly you are sending string object as plain from the server you need to use `JavaScriptSerializer or JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json.NET)`